# How can we perform reset function in master page of aspx page?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, unobtrusive-javascript

```
function reset1()
            {
                alert("123");
                document.form1.reset();
                return false();
            }
```

I want to have resetting controls of a master page using Javascript, but it doesn't work properly.
Can anyone help me to get through to it working?

Above is the function of reset which I used for resetting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is case-sensitive.  Is it possible that you have your form name wrong?  Try to use an index instead...

```
document.forms[0].reset();
```

Or perhaps you are not sure what `reset` is supposed to do.  It restores each element on the form to its default value.  It should do *exactly* what a `<input type="reset"/>` would do.